# Returning Array in mysql Select

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I'm trying to group inventory results by the model and manufacturer name, display the amount of items matching and 1 result per grouping. With that said, I'd like to try and retrieve all inventory id's within the group. Wondering if this is possible... Any ideas?

FYI - I'm using Laravel, the line in question is the ->selectRaw(CambridgeID as CambridgeIDArray)

```
$getMatchingInventory = DB::table('inventory')
                                ->selectRaw('*, count(*) as groupTotal')
                                ->whereRaw("MATCH(ManufacturerNameMatch, SubCategoryNameMatch, MainCategoryNameMatch, Model_Name, Title_Override, Description_Old) AGAINST ('$final' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")
                                ->selectRaw('CambridgeID as CambridgeIDArray')
                                ->groupBy('Model_Name', 'ManufacturerNameMatch')
                                ->having('Units_OnHand', '>=', '1')
                                ->orderBy('ManufacturerNameMatch')
                                //->paginate(15);
                                ->get();
```

Comment: Can't you put `Units_OnHand` in the WHERE statement, btw? See below for your answer (`GROUP_CONCAT` is what you are looking for).

Comment: @ldg thank you for that recommendation, that helps clean it up a bit.

Comment: It should make it slightly faster too, as might grouping by id instead of string and creating a composite index on those columns, just depends the size and needs of your db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$getMatchingInventory = DB::table('inventory')
                            ->select(DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(CambridgeID) as `CambridgeIDArray`, count(*) as `groupTotal`"))
                            ->whereRaw("MATCH(ManufacturerNameMatch, SubCategoryNameMatch, MainCategoryNameMatch, Model_Name, Title_Override, Description_Old) AGAINST ('$final' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")
                            ->groupBy('Model_Name', 'ManufacturerNameMatch')
                            ->having('Units_OnHand', '>=', '1')
                            ->orderBy('ManufacturerNameMatch') 
                            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `GROUP_CONCAT` for that, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

You can use specify output format options (e.g., SEPARATOR) and use additional string manipulation as needed within the `GROUP_CONCAT`.

(Fyi, using raw MySQL, at least for this question, would make it easier to parse.)

Comment: thanks again for the documentation and helpful response.